# Why does periodic commit throw open transaction error for 11.8 example in 2.2.0-M02?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

With Neo4j 2.2.0-M02, [11.8. Importing CSV files with Cypher" on 2.2.0-m02](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html) **fails** with InvalidSemantics with "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" to load CSV in Cypher.

Error: *"Executing queries that use periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was just a bug in M02, it is fixed in M03

Comment: It happens to me on a 3.0.4 version using Talend and the neo4j-jdbc 3.0 connector as explained here: https://neo4j.com/blog/official-neo4j-jdbc-driver-3-0/